# Error message in C

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I have a problem with compiling C application, the errors that are shown are senseless. I don't know where to start looking for a solution.

Here is the code:

```
static char* FilterCreate(
    void* arg,
    const char* const* key_array, const size_t* key_length_array,
    int num_keys,
    size_t* filter_length) {
  *filter_length = 4;
  char* result = malloc(4); // error: error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type' C:\Projects\myleveldb\db\c_test.c
  memcpy(result, "fake", 4);
  return result;
}
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fChIr.png) is the fullscreen screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

What might cause such error?

Comment: Please post actual code and actual error messages. In particular, none of the error messages you show corresponds to any of the lines you show.

Comment: Don't just stick a screen shot of your IDE. Your system gives you lines numbers and relevant sections. Write our your question in a coherent manner.

Comment: Just so you know, although VC++ is OK with C++ code, it rather sucks as a C compiler.  It doesn't implement all of C99, even, and apparently has no plans to.

Comment: Sorry, I'll fix everything up

Comment: @cHao: It doesn't suck as a C compiler, it does just fine as a C89 compiler.  It's just not a C99 compiler.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are compiling C code with a C89/90 compiler.

In classic C (C89/90) it is illegal to declare variables in the middle of a block. All variables must be declared at the beginning of a block.

Once you started to write *statements*, like `*filter_length = 4`, it means that you are done with *declarations*. You are no longer allowed to introduce variable declarations in this block. Move your declaration higher and the code will compile.

---

In C language *declarations* are not *statements* (as opposed to C++ where *declaration* is just a form of *statement*). And in C89/90 the grammar for compound statement is:

```
compound-statement:
  { declaration-list[opt] statement-list[opt] }
```

meaning that all declarations have to come first, at the beginning of the block.

Note that in C99 declarations are not statements either. But the grammar for compound statement has been changed to:

```
compound-statement:
  { block-item-list[opt] }

block-item-list:
  block-item
  block-item-list block-item

block-item:
  declaration
  statement
```

which is why you can interleave declarations and statements in C99.

Comment: Can you please quote the reference which says this : *"In C89/90 it is illegal to declare variables in the middle of the block"*.

Comment: Looks like your gun is a little faster than fine today.

Comment: @Nawaz: I don't know whether the standard states it like that explicitly. But grammar for *compound statement* in C89/90 is `{ declaration list statement-list }`. *Declarations* are not considered *statements* in C89/90 (as opposed to C++). In C99 declarations are not statements either, but the grammar for *compound statement* explicitly allows interleaving them.

Comment: @Nawaz: Quoting the standard is not helpful here.  OP just didn't know there was a rule in C89 that forbids mixed declarations and code.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield: I had requested for the quote from the spec, not the OP. So I wanted to know it, not the OP.

Comment: @Nawaz There's not likely to be a single line in the spec that forbids it. It was a feature that was added in C99.